# Load parts of an XML file into a DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have a DataSet with some Datatables and I am saving this DataSet as XML file (C#) ..is there any way to load only some parts of this XML file into the DataSet when I start my program instead of loading all the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position your `XmlReader` on the start of the fragment you want, then call `DataTable.ReadXml`.